# Manipulate a running deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

```
$(function(){

    var dfd = $.when( $('div').eq(0).fadeOut(1000) );

    // ADD NOW NEW FUNCTION DO dfd

    dfd.then(function(){
        alert();
    });

});
```

Is it possible to add another function to dfd deferred object if it is running but it isn't yet resolved?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't matter if it's resolved or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear, but I think that you want to check whether the deferred is resolved and add another callback if it's not:

http://jsfiddle.net/RT23y/1/

Essentially you can just check

```
if (dfd.state() == 'resolved')
```

to see whether another callback can be added.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard jQuery method chain we would expect `.fadeOut()` to return jQuery, however in the expression ...

```
$.when( $('div').eq(0).fadeOut(1000) )...;
```

... by a piece of internal jQuery magic, the parameter passed to `$.when()` is actually a promise derived from the `fx` queue of `$('div').eq(0)`. To be explicit, we would write ...

```
$.when( $('div').eq(0).fadeOut(1000).promise('fx') )...;
```

There's actually no reason to use `$.when()` unless you need to do something in response to two or more promises. We can therfore write ...

```
var promise = $('div').eq(0).fadeOut(1000).promise();
```

... giving a promise to which any number of "done" callbacks can be attached in a variety of ways.

Here's a sample of what is possible :

```
var promise = $('div').eq(0).fadeOut(1000).promise();

promise.then(function() {
    alert('done 1');
});

promise.done(function() {
    alert('done 2');
});

promise.then(function() {
    alert('done 3');
}).always(function() {
    alert('done 4');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U4AgZ/)**

Answer (score -1):

You can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
$('div').eq(0).promise().done(function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.